# How can you change the perl 6 version you are using or install a new module for the one Comma uses?

Tags: raku, commaide

When I start a new project in Comma, it pops up the version I am going to use. Instead of allowing me to select from every version in my rakudobrew list, there's a single option, which is not the one I have selected on the command line. When I run a script, it does not find the modules that are already installed. So how can I

- Change the version of Perl 6 it's using for the current project? Or else
- How can I install the module it's not finding from Comma IDE?

I can of course get out of comma, change the global Rakudo version, install the module, and then go back to whichever I'm using, but I was wondering how to do that from Comma itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To change Perl 6 SDK for the project you go to `File -> Project Settings` and select project's SDK. Usually it suggests you to choose from not SDKs available from rakudobrew, but one available in your `PATH`(global, possibly not configured by rakudobrew for this particular shell). So it looks like Perl 6 you have in PATH is not the one that you use from the command line, so the modules are not available.
- Clicking on `New -> Perl 6 SDK` in Project Settings you can manually specify a path to a Perl 6 `bin` directory you want to have as an SDK, so for rakudobrew you should specify e.g. `/home/$user/.rakudobrew/versions/moar-2019.07/install/bin` directory. If it will be the same location you have in `which perl6` in your command line where you install modules, it should work.
- Right now Comma does not do things related to package management, though this feature is planned.